# How can I calculate the percentage, for each row, of the sum of the COUNT(*) in a grouped query? - SQL

Tags: sql, sqlite, count, sum

I'm having trouble with a required query in a project at an online learning website. Having a database that looks like this:

[image: Database structure, SQLite]

I need to execute the following query:

Returns a SQL query string that will find the sports a country has
won medals in. It should include the number of medals, aliased as 'count',
as well as the percentage of this country's wins the sport represents,
aliased as 'percent'. Optionally ordered by the given field in the specified direction.

I have the filtering part solved. For the first part, given a country 'Norway', I have:

```
SELECT sport, count(*) as count 
FROM GOLDMEDAL 
WHERE COUNTRY = "Norway" GROUP BY SPORT
```

I don't know how to code the percentage part. I know I need to somehow SUM the total rows for each sport and then calculate, but I'm having trouble with subqueries. Here's one I tried, which does not work:

```
SELECT SPORT, COUNT(*) as count, 
       (COUNT(*)*100)/(SELECT SUM(COUNT(*)) 
                       FROM GOLDMEDAL 
                       WHERE COUNTRY = "Norway" 
                       GROUP BY SPORT) 
FROM GOLDMEDAL 
WHERE COUNTRY = "Norway" 
GROUP BY SPORT;
```

EDIT: Solved it.

```
SELECT SPORT, 
       COUNT(*), 
       COUNT(*)*100/(SELECT COUNT(*) 
                     FROM GOLDMEDAL 
                     WHERE COUNTRY = 'Norway') 
FROM GOLDMEDAL 
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Norway' 
GROUP BY SPORT;
```

I couldn't tell that by counting every row where the country was norway, it got back all the medals the country won for each sport. Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below the query will help you to meet the requirement

```
select sport,count(*) as count,(count(*)*100)/(Select count(*) from goldmedal where 
country = "Norway") as percent 
from goldmedal where country = "Norway" group by sport;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use below query -

```
SELECT SPORT,
       COUNT(*) as count,
       (COUNT(*)*100)/(SELECT COUNT(*) FROM GOLDMEDAL) as percent
FROM GOLDMEDAL
WHERE COUNTRY = "Norway"
GROUP BY SPORT;
```

Comment: Hey Ankit! Correct me if I'm wrong, but I think the subquery needs to filter out as well for the country requested, if not it will calculate the percentage for that sport of the country over every medal won by every country. I posted the solution I got, thank you so much!

Answer (score 0):

The best way to do this uses window functions, not subqueries:

```
SELECT sport, COUNT(*) as count,
       (COUNT(*) * 100.0 / SUM(COUNT(*)) OVER ()) as percent
FROM GOLDMEDAL 
WHERE COUNTRY = 'Norway'
GROUP BY SPORT
ORDER BY percent DESC;
```